# Issue in FileUpload - Null Value for Multipart File when deploy on remote host server but it works fine on localhost server

Tags: java, spring, file-upload, multipart

I have a jsp file `UploadCoupon.jsp` as follows for image uploading

```
<form:form commandName="uploadcoupon" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <form:input type="file" path="couponImage" class="file_1 required"/><br/>
    <form:errors path="couponImage" cssClass="error" style="color:red" /><br/>
    <input id="uploadCouponButton" type="submit" value="" class="form-submit" />
</form:form>
```

Bean class is `Coupon.java` which looks like below

```
public class Coupon {

    MultipartFile couponImage;

    public MultipartFile getCouponImage() {
        return couponImage;
    }

    public void setCouponImage(MultipartFile couponImage) {
        this.couponImage = couponImage;
    }

}
```

Dispatcher servlet has following code

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>
```

Controller `UploadCoupon.java` is as follows

```
public class UploadCoupon extends SimpleFormController
{

    public UploadCoupon()
    {
        setCommandClass(Coupon.class);
        setCommandName("uploadcoupon");
    }

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    Object command,
                                    BindException errors) throws Exception {

        try {

            Coupon coupon = (Coupon)command;

            MultipartFile multipartFile = coupon.getCouponImage();

            // image type of file processing...

        } catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println("Exception -"+e.getMessage());
        }

        mv = new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("UploadCoupon.htm");
        return mv;

    }

}
```

This code work fine when deployed on Glassfish server on localhost, but when I am deploying it on remote host on Glassfish server multipartFile object is null and NullPointerException occurs. I can't understand what is problem in deploying it on remote host?

Answer (score 0):

Looks more like a configuration problem. I too had this on tomcat and the problem was the max post size limit. You should configure properly the `maxPostSize` property of your `http-service` / `http-listener`. A value of 0 means unlimited size.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I have tried it but still it is not working. I am still waiting for some solution.

Answer (score 0):

I understand where the problem is. Don't use **httpRequest** object before getting image from it. In my case I had used **httpRequest** object in filter before calling spring controller  to check Http Session. Now I have removed this filter in case of file uploading and my code is working good.